# KendoUI template is invalid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm creating a KendoUI template like this:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-list flow-list">
                <li class="nav-header">Flows in action</li>
                <script id="flow-list" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                    #for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ {#
                        <li>#=data[i]#</li>
                    #}#
                </script>
            </ul>
```

And here is how I'm passing data:

```
//Get the external template definition using a jQuery selector
var template = kendo.template($("#flow-list").html());

//Create some dummy data
var data = ["Todd", "Steve", "Burke"];

//Execute the template
template(data);
```

Running the above code shows me an error saying `"Invalid template"`

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the closing parenthesis of the `for` loop.

```
#for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ /* missing ) */ {#
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsbin.com/ihivez/1/edit

Comment: In addition, *remember* that invoking the template you generate the HTML but you do not insert it into your page. You have to do what Atanas did on the working demo `$(".nav-list").append(template(data));`

Comment: @Atanas & Emiliano - Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I'll need to be more sharp..